# What does ${xyz##* } mean in a shell file?

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to understand a shell script. What does `${device_info##* }` do?

```
device_info=$(ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/my-disk)
relative_path=${device_info##* }
```

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${x##p}` is a parameter expansion in POSIX or Bourne shell which removes the longest (because of `##`, there is also a shortest match with `#` operator) match of *p* from the shell variable *x*. The (file name globbing, not regular expression) pattern which is actually matched in your case is '`*`' (which means any number characters terminated by a blank).

You can test it yourself:

```
A="a b cc"
echo longest: ${A##* }
echo shortest: ${A#* }
```

Which will print `longest cc` and `shortest b cc`.

In your case it will remove all but the last column from the `ls` output.

The patterns are documented in the shell man page (*Parameter Expansion* section in `man bash`). It is also documented in section 2.6.2 of the [Open Group POSIX shell command language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html).

Comment: Thank you @eckes. Is there any good resource to learn about these nitty gritty of shell scripts?

Comment: There might be tutorials somewhere, dont know a good one. But I expanded the answer and referenced the section in the man page (of bash), it gives at least a short description for all the patterns supported.

Comment: @codefx: Shotts' [Linux Command Line](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php), Lhunath's [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), and the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) are good reads. See also the [annotated reading list at Bash Hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/tutoriallist).

Comment: Great answer. Kudos for referencing the POSIX specification which implies that it can be used in scripts that should be portable to all POSIX shells such as Bash, varieties of the Korn Shell (`ksh`) and Debian's Almquist shell (`dash`).